# Current User Method for Bigcommerce

Tags: javascript, authentication, e-commerce, bigcommerce

I would like to create a current user method for my Bigcommerce site/store.  Is this possible?

For example:

```
if (current_user === XYZ_user) {
  do this
}  else {
  do this other thing
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: A "current user method"? What does that even mean? Do you mean you check who the current user is? If so, that's absolutely possible, as you've shown in your pseudo code.

Comment: judging by your answer you were able to infer what I was asking from the pseudo code, which was the point of putting it there in the first place, I don't see the issue or the need to downtick the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer the most immediate question, and I'll assume you're not using the new Stencil platform.

Use the %%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%% and %%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerLastName%% variables that you see here:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/store_wide_variables

Stealing your pseudocode:

```
var XYZ_user = 'BobJohnson'
var current_user = '%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%%%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerLastName%%'
if (current_user === XYZ_user) {
  do this
}  else {
  do this other thing
}
```

These variables are available on every page, whereas certain other variables like the email address have incomplete availability.

However, it might be better to put these customers into a group and use the %%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupId%% variable instead. You can get the customer group ID via the API or by looking at the URL in the control panel when editing that group.

For example:

```
if (%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupId%% === 4) {
  do this
}  else {
  do this other thing
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nathan, that all worked great and opened up the world of BC globals for me.  Much appreciated!

Comment: FYI that BC now offers a JS-based solution for securely verifying customer identity: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#identifying-logged-in-customers-securely